# How to define ngModel in ng-select with preselect

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-ngselect

Hey guys i have a little issue with the ng-select angular code i have an simple code

HTML

```
 <label>Roles</label>

        <ng-select [multiple]="true"
            [(ngModel)]="user.roles" 
            [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" 
            required
            placeholder="Edit roles">
            <ng-option  *ngFor="let role of roles" [value]="role.name" name="role.name">{{role.name | json}}</ng-option>
        </ng-select>
```

And in the .ts file i have following properties

```
 ngOnInit(): void {
    this.user = new User();
    this.id = this.route.snapshot.params['id']
    this.userService.getUserById(this.id).subscribe(data => {
    this.user = data; 
  this.selRoles = data.roles.map(role => {return {name: role.name}});
  this.user.roles = [];
  this.user.roles.push(...this.selRoles);
  console.log("user.roles :  " + (this.user.roles.map(f=>f.name))); 
 =>The Output of the console.log is := user.roles :  write,read,write /Should it eather be [write,read,write]??
```

but the ng-select is not working as the picture shows is it maybe that the user.roles is defined as roles!: Array<{name:string}>; and not like a testVar = []

```
export class User {
    id!: number;
    firstName!: string;
    lastName!: string;
    emailId!: string;
    **roles!: Array<{name:string}>;**
  }
```

So do you have any ideas how to fix this issue or how to transform from roles!: Array<{name:string}>; into roles = [];?

[image: ng-select & ngModel]

[image]

When i open the select box and click on a option it is working fine but the preselection is missing the name property. Why?

**EDIT**
now i defined a `selected :any ;` then i try to push the roles property to the selected variable: Like

```
      this.selected.push (data.roles.map(role => {return {name: role.name}}));
```

but still shows just an empty select? What to do?

Comment: If you use `map()` for console.log() there is no array any more. The output is correct. Try `console.log("user.roles :  ", this.user.roles);` then you'll see the array.

Comment: ok you mean like it is allready in a simple array => array : []; Yes the console.log contains then the following: user.roles :  [object Object],[object Object] so two objects which is correct but it is not showing in the gui it is just an empty X with no value